# Looped algorithm to increment a number until it reaches a value, then decrement

Tags: javascript, algorithm, while-loop, increment, decrement

I'm trying to increment a number until it reaches a value (say 100), then make it decrement until it reaches 0, and have all this run in a while loop.

The code seems correct, but the browser is freezing, so I can't check in the console if there's a flaw in the algorithm.

```
var ceiling = 100;
var floor = 1;
var x = 1;
var step = 1; 

setInterval(function(){
    while(1) {
        while(x + step <= ceiling) {
            x += step;
            document.write(x + ' ');        
        }
        while(x - step >= floor) {
            x -= step;
            document.write(x + ' ');        
        }
    }
}, 1500);
```

I've used setInterval here to slow down execution and avoid some buffering issue with the browser. It shouldn't be a problem since I have 16GB of RAM, but it might depend on how the browser can use/access that too in one tab.

I've also tried wrapping the setInterval function inside another function and execute it, with the same result.

Comment: How do you expect your code to escape the infinite while loop...

Comment: It's supposed to be an infinite loop, albeit an infinite loop with a slowed down execution.

Comment: Why don't you do a simple test to see if your infinite loop is really "slowed down" like you think it is? Do you actually think setInterval affects the loop inside the function? Test your theories out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers have already pointed out the problems with your endless loop and with using document.write.

I think this does what you want:

```
var ceiling = 100;
var floor = 1;
var x = 1;
var step = 1;

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(x);
  x += step;
  if (x === ceiling || x === floor) {
    step = -step;
  }
}, 1500);
```

setInterval is essentially your while(1) loop.

Comment: I've already made it work by adding `return` at the end of the loop, but I'll accept this answer since it works with less code.

Answer (score 3):

You have a while(1) loop which basically is a infinite loop, even if no code is executed, it will freeze the browser.

Comment: If you use a setInterval with the right setting, it shouldn't freeze the browser. Who said infinite loops are unusable in algorithms? This code works in the console if I replace document.write with console.log, by the way. So, there's nothing inherently non-functional about running an infinite loop, provided you slow it down enough for the browser buffer to catch up with the execution speed.

Comment: You guys need to leave off with the "infinite loop" thing.  that tiny function will take almost no memory at all.  So there will be a steady growth of "concurrent" functions running.  Maybe he wants to plot a chart of how many set interval functions he can have running at once.  maybe he's trying to understand the behavior of multiple setinterval functions running at once.

Comment: I'm actually trying to model the behaviour of a particle which keeps growing up to a point then it starts decreasing (in a canvas), all in an continuous loop. I'm sure this is possible. Everyone, thanks for the help.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing There will never be more than one function running at once. The event loop cannot start a new function if one is still running. It's all synchronous.

Comment: @Shashank hmm that's right. there's no reason for the outer while anyways.

Comment: You can try this in your console @Olavi Sau. It works:
`var x = 1;
 setInterval(function(){  
  while(true){
   document.body.innerHTML += ((x++)+'<br>');
            return;
  }  
 }, 1000);`

Comment: Exactly, but the incremented value of x is saved, so at the next execution the loop will increment it again, then return.

Comment: @kuantik Yes, but in your original code you are never returning from any function. Remember that JavaScript is synchronous, so your `setInterval` will wait for the function to end or return something. Since you are never breaking out of the while loop, the program blocks forever

Answer (score 1):

document.write is only intended to be used on the first rendering of the document. since you are doing an interval, then the doc is already rendered, and you can't use document.write.  instead, you need to append your text to the body or a div

Comment: You're probably right, since it works in the console if I output the number (x) using console.log. I'll try to append it as a text node or something similar.

Comment: @kuantik you could try document.body.innerHTML+=(x+"<br>")